# Where should custom javascript be injected into a Wordpress theme?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am helping a friend build a wordpress site using a purchased custom theme as his parent theme. There is also a child theme.

I've written some javascript to listen for clicks on specific links, and to change CSS in response to them. I can make this work in another environment, but we're trying to figure out how to get it to execute in Wordpress.

We have tried putting it in the `index.php` (most logical source to me, since that's to me that makes the most sense, but obviously WordPress works differently).

**So all I am trying to figure out is, where in wordpress do you put the script tag (where you put code, not referencing jQuery we already have that)?**

Comment: Is it a custom theme or is he building one from scratch?

Comment: Thank you @JakubBilko for quick response. He says the parent theme is custom (meaning he bought it) and he has a child theme. I'm not sure what the difference is, so please excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the index.php script will only load the WordPress framework and run it, you need to add your js code in the theme/template files.

a little quote from the official word press site:

> JavaScript in Template Files
>
> The safe and recommended method of adding
> JavaScript to a WordPress generated page, and WordPress Theme or
> Plugin, is by using wp_enqueue_script(). This function includes the
> script if it hasn't already been included, and safely handles
> dependencies.

you can read more [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript)

In my opinion, the best is that you should create a js file with the code you want to run and upload to your theme/template folder, and then add it with a script tag as the link i've provided explains.

And my advice is to not embed the code directly in the template file but load it from a javascript file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/pathto/yourscript.js"></script>
```

Comment: shouldn't send newbies off to do the wrong thing. `wp_enqueue_script()` is the "best practice" answer.

Comment: I did not send anyone to do anything. I've just quoted the official site and added an opinion about it.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that in different ways:

**Including the script in your footer for example**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/pathto/yourscript.js"></script>
```

Or using the `wp_enqueue_script` function, [more info](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Comment: @Omeed you can add your **own script** after jquery!

Comment: yeah sorry for my ignorance, this is all so foreign to me. Usually this is the most simple task imaginable, you just add the <script> ..code.. </script>. Not used to wordpress. Thank you @gonzalon

Comment: There is no more correct answers than use wp_enqueue_script. If you hardcode scripts, stylesheets adding in theme, you can`t later handle this dynamically.